# Routing based on standard PHP query string

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

As you know, Zend Framework (v1.10) uses routing based on slash separated params, ex.

```
[server]/controllerName/actionName/param1/value1/param2/value2/
```

Queston is: How to force Zend Framework, to retrive action and controller name using standard PHP query string, in this case:

```
[server]?controller=controllerName&action=actionName&param1=value1&param2=value2
```

I've tried:

```
protected function _initRequest()
{
    // Ensure the front controller is initialized
    $this->bootstrap('FrontController');

    // Retrieve the front controller from the bootstrap registry
    $front = $this->getResource('FrontController');

    $request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
    $request->setControllerName($_GET['controller']);
    $request->setActionName($_GET['action']);
    $front->setRequest($request);

    // Ensure the request is stored in the bootstrap registry
    return $request;
}
```

But it doesn't worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$front->setRequest($request);
```

The line only sets the Request object instance. The frontController still runs the request through a router where it gets assigned what controller / action to call.

You need to create your own router:

```
class My_Router implements Zend_Controller_Router_Interface
{
    public function route(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $controller = 'index';
        if(isset($_GET['controller'])) {
            $controller = $_GET['controller'];
        }

        $request->setControllerName($controller);

        $action = 'index';
        if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
            $action = $_GET['action'];
        }

        $request->setActionName($action);
    }
}}
```

Then in your bootstrap:

```
protected function _initRouter()
{
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $frontController = $this->getResource('frontController');

    $frontController->setRouter(new My_Router());
}
```

Comment: It almost worked, I had to extend My_Router from Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite or implement remaining interface methods. First solution was quicker;) Now it works great. Thx!

Comment: According to the manual you were supposed to only have to implement that method. The API seemed to say otherwise so I was confused. You might also try extending Zend_Controller_Router_Abstract instead of Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite. They need a better example in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: `$router->removeDefaultRoutes()`, then `$request->getParams()` or `$request->getServer()`?