# How to get original URL from a specific Controller + Action

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've been working on a project and everything's fine until my partner wants to request to an original URL without rewriting.

For example:
He wants to call to

> http://mydomain.com/index.php?module=default&controller=check&action=index

instead of

> http://mydomain.com/default/controller/index.

Is there any way that i can make the above URL working?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390096/routing-based-on-standard-php-query-string

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact Rob Allen <sup>(Author of Zend Framework in Action)</sup> has written an excellent article explain just how to do this.

[Zend Framework URLs without mod_rewrite](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend-framework-urls-without-mod_rewrite/)